# Python group list into subgroups with constraints

Tags: python, grouping

I really searched for this one, because I am almost certain some variation has been asked before but I couldn't put in the correct terms into Google to get a result that matches what I am trying to do. Generally seems like people are looking for the total combinations without constraints.

I am trying to do the following:

Given a list like this:

`[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]` group it into as many groups of `[1, 2, 3]` as possible

So

`[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]` -> `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`

`[1, 1, 2, 3, 3]` -> `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3]]`

`[1, 1, 3, 3, 5]` -> `[[1, 3, 5], [1, 3]]`

`[1, 4, 4, 7]` -> `[[1, 4, 7], [4]]`

**Notes:**

1. Input will always be sorted, but the values of these numbers is not known, so it will need to work in general sense.
2. The idea is I have objects with certain attributes that need to be grouped together to create a different object, but sometimes I am given repeats (and potentially incomplete repeats) -- ie, I used to think that the attributes of my objects will always just be `[1, 2, 3]` but turns out sometimes I can get `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]` and I need a way to break that into two `[1, 2, 3]` lists to create an intermediate object downstream.

Comment: Is it possible you'll get input with more than three unique values? If so, do you still want sublists of length three?

Comment: @CrazyChucky - yes, it could be more than 3 unique values. I could have something like `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4]` and that should become `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [3]]`. Not sure how to best describe the constraints, but I suppose you could say I want the longest combinations possible with non-repeated elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zip_longest` and `groupby` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, groupby

def f(l):
    z = zip_longest(*[list(g) for _, g in groupby(l)])
    return [[j for j in i if j is not None] for i in z]
```

Usage:

```
>>> f([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

>>> f([1, 1, 2, 3, 3])
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3]]

>>> f([1, 1, 3, 3, 5])
[[1, 3, 5], [1, 3]]

>>> f([1, 4, 4, 7])
[[1, 4, 7], [4]]

# Update
>>> f(sorted([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2]))
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]

# Update 2
>>> f([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3])
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]
```

**Update**

Alternative version suggested by @cards using `filterfalse`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, groupby, filterfalse

def f(l):
    z = zip_longest(*[list(g) for _, g in groupby(l)])
    return [list(filterfalse(lambda j: j is None, i)) for i in z]
```

Comment: ... for sake of completeness why not to mention `itertools.filterfalse`? ->  `[list(filterfalse(lambda x: x is None, i)) for i in z]`